# Run own function for each GroupBy in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

Have to process rows in Spark/Scala, pls help.

I have the below dataframe DF1:

```
ACC_SECURITY|ACCOUNT_NO|COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|SECURITY_ID|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
|3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2|   18063|               P|         |             0|           0|
|3FA34782290X2|  3FA34782|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0102|     5322|      290X2|    -863|               N|         |             0|           0|
|3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2| -108926|               N|         |             0|           0|
|9211530135G71|  92115301|    08036C|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0154|     8380|      35G71|    8003|               P|         |             0|           0|
|9211530235G71|  92115302|    08036C|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0144|     8382|      35G71|   -2883|               N|         |             0|           0|
```

Dataframe DF2:

```
|ENTITY|MATRIX|PRIORITY|LONG_CODE|SHORT_CODE|
+------+------+--------+---------+----------+
    300|    00|   16600|     0101|      5322|
    300|    00|   19900|     0101|      5279|
    300|    00|  298300|     0102|      5279|
    300|    00|   17800|     0154|      8382|
    300|    00|  505900|     0233|      5279|
```

I want to Group by on above dataframe by SECURITY_ID...will then get below 2 groups:

```
ACC_SECURITY|ACCOUNT_NO|COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|SECURITY_ID|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
|3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2|   18063|               P|         |             0|           0|
|3FA34782290X2|  3FA34782|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0102|     5322|      290X2|    -863|               N|         |             0|           0|
|3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2| -108926|               N|         |             0|           0|

ACC_SECURITY|ACCOUNT_NO|COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|SECURITY_ID|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
|9211530135G71|  92115301|    08036C|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0154|     8380|      35G71|    8003|               P|         |             0|           0|
|9211530235G71|  92115302|    08036C|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0144|     8382|      35G71|   -2883|               N|         |             0|           0|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
```

Then in each group, I want to
- take LONG_IND from the row where QUANTITY is positive, SHORT_IND from row where QUANTITY is negative
and look up priorities from the priority dataframe DF2, sort by ascending order of PRIORITY

Calculating only for first group, I get below priorities data:

```
|LONG_CODE|SHORT_CODE|PRIORITY|
+---------+----------+--------+|
0101|      5322|    16600|
0101|      5279|    19900|
0102|      5279|    298300|
```

Then process DF1 by adding Quantities based on above priority... here we do 2 iterations 
So Row1.Quantity adds up with Row2.Quantity by updating other columns based on if result is Positive or Negative
- ALLOC_QUANTITY - how much quantity is neutralized (here its 18063 - 863, so 863 is neutralized
- NET_QUANTITY - how much quantity is remaining to be processed for 2nd iteration (here its 18063 - 863 = 17200 is remaining)
- PROCESSED - Put "p" if NET_QUANTITY is Zero. So here only 2nd row got processed, so only gets Processed=P

Iteration 1: Processing Rows 1 and 2. Quantity = 18063 + (-863) = 17200 (Positive quantity retains other columns from 1st row)

```
ACC_SECURITY|ACCOUNT_NO|COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|SECURITY_ID|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
    3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2|   18063|               P|       N  |           863|        17200|
    3FA34782290X2|  3FA34782|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0102|     5322|      290X2|    -863|               N|       P  |             0|           0|
    3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2| -108926|               N|          |             0|           0|
```

Iteration 2: Processing Rows 1 and 3. Quantity = 17200 + (-108926) = -91726 (Negative quantity retains other columns from 3rd row)

```
ACC_SECURITY|ACCOUNT_NO|COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|SECURITY_ID|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2|   18063|               P|       P  |           863|        17200|
3FA34782290X2|  3FA34782|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0102|     5322|      290X2|    -863|               N|       P  |             0|           0|
3FA34789290X2|  3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      290X2| -108926|               N|       P  |             0|           0|
```

Here 1st row.Processed becomes P and 3rd row.Processed becomes P only because group is all finished processing with 3 rows.

I tried with below, but not able to crack it, pls help how to create a function to do above iterations for rows in each group. Maybe using GroupByKey and mapgroups.

```
case class AllocOneProcess(ACC_SECURITY: String, ACCOUNT_NO: String, COSTCENTER: String, BU: String, MPU: String, LONG_IND: String, SHORT_IND: String, SECURITY_ID: String, QUANTITY: String, POS_NEG_QUANTITY: String, PROCESSED: String, ALLOC_QUANTITY: Integer, NET_QUANTITY: Integer)

val toBeProcessedAllocOneDF2 = toBeProcessedAllocOneDF.as[AllocOneProcess]
        val toBeProcessedAllocOneDF3 = toBeProcessedAllocOneDF.toDF()

        prioritymatrixDF.show()

        //toBeProcessedAllocOneDF
        val x = toBeProcessedAllocOneDF2
          .groupByKey(_.SECURITY_ID)
          .mapGroups{
            case (nameKey, df) => {
            allocOneProcess(df,)
          }
          }
```

Comment: This question isn't clear, please review it so we can try to help !

Comment: I have to GroupBy Security_ID in DF1, take list of LONG_IND and SHORT_IND and search in DF2. Then based on priority of a combination of LONG_IND, SHORT_IND from diff rows (LONG_IND from DF1.ROW1 and SHORT_IND from DF2.ROW2 constitutes a priority), process DF1 by summing the quantities (only when quantities are in plus and minus) are in opposite signage . So lets say the priority of DF1.ROW1.LONG_IND and DF1.ROW2.SHORT_IND is higher than DF1.ROW1.LONG_IND and DF1.ROW3.SHORT_IND, then add DF1.ROW1.QUANTITY and DF1.ROW2.QUANTITY to get 18063-863=17200. Then I have one more row DF1.ROW3 and so on,

Comment: So after processing DF1.ROW1 and DF1.ROW2, I get 17200 which is positive, so I create a new row instead of these 2 rows with all column data from DF1.ROW1 except Quantity is the sum=17200. We take other columns from ROW1 in this new row as final quantity is positive. Now take this new row and work with DF1.ROW3. As new row and ROW3 have opposite quantities (17200 and -108926), one positive and one negative, we sum the quantities to get 17200-108926 = -91,726. This new row will have all data from DF1.ROW3 with Quantity as -91,726. We take other columns from ROW3 as final quantity is negative.

Comment: So at end of processing first group with Security_Id 290X2, we end up with 3 rows becoming 1 row with all details of ROW3 and Quantity being -91,726.

Comment: On a high level, we need to do this. In DF1, Group on SECURITY_ID, take LONG_IND from Positive Quantity rows, SHORT_IND from Negative quantity rows, check this combination for priority in DF2, then process DF1. At end of processing each SECURITY in DF1, we end up with one row if we have opposite signage quantities. If no opposite signage quantities, then we just let the rows remain.